# I want do download a csv file from a web page using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am doing a test on a website where a link exist as a button "save as csv". I want to save this by using jmeter. Can you please suggest what will be the right path to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the link has [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) which points to the location of the CSV file, i.e.

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/to/file.csv">Save as CSV</a>
```

It means  that you need to send a simple HTTP [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to the location of the `href` attribute of the link. The relevant configuration of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler would be something like:

[image]

If you additionally want to save the file to your hard drive - use [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, see [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more information if needed.

If you have problems with constructing this or that JMeter HTTP Request manually - remember that you can always just record it using your browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)